# Is there any way to get a full total record count from SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

[The `SqlBulkCopy` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) has a reporting mechanism built in: the `SqlRowsCopied` event.  Every `NotifyAfter` records, it fires this event and gives you a running total of how many rows have been copied so far.

This is great, as long as your total number of rows is an exact multiple of the `NotifyAfter` property.  But if it's not, you get an inaccurate count.  In the worst case scenario, where your total number of rows is *less than* the `NotifyAfter` property, your total gets reported as 0!

Is there any way to get an accurate count out of this class, without having to either resort to a separate query as [the doc page does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.sqlrowscopied?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) or set `NotifyAfter` to 1 and slow the copying to a crawl?

Comment: Whenever I need to run a check of how many rows I've copied over, I always subtracted the count of rows prior to the copy from the count of rows post copy. This would only work with _adding_ new rows. If updating, since row count wouldn't change, this wouldn't be accurate

Comment: You can wrap the input source in your own IDataReader implementation and count the input rows there, I think.